# Another question for a quicker way to perform a running total

Tags: excel

I need to create a spill formula for a running total

[image]

I'm able to create this formula using

```
=SUMIF($B$2:$D$2,"<="&COLUMN($B$2:$D$2)-1,B3:D3)
```

But I'm not able to understand how to make it work as one formula only so that I don't have to drag for each row hoping someone can assist

Comment: You need SCAN() function.

Comment: Yes I have that

Comment: I am writing from mobile. Once I am infront of computer, I will post formula.

Comment: @Harun24hr how can I avoid the offset. Can you suggest

Comment: Is the number of columns fixed at three, or could it be potentially more?

Comment: @Rakshitha Check new answers.

Comment: Hey Jos yes it is more than three it's like 14 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-volatile alternative:

`=LET(ζ,B2:D8,ξ,SCAN(0,ζ,LAMBDA(κ,λ,κ+λ)),γ,SEQUENCE(ROWS(ζ),,0),ξ-IF(γ=0,0,INDEX(ξ,γ,COLUMNS(ζ))))`

Comment: Nice one. I was also thinking to use scan function.

Comment: I will let you know once I have tried

Comment: Jos you are life saver it worked too fast great. Really perfect

Answer (score 2):

We can use OFFSET and SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF(OFFSET(B3,SEQUENCE(ROWS(B3:D8),,0),0,1,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(B3:D8))),"<>")
```

[image]

Comment: Yas it works but we are not taking the header here and what does offset function do. Also will it perform fast because originally I have a data of around 10000 lines.

Comment: 1. with the offset we no longer need the check in SUMIF to get it to do the running total.  I assumed that was a trick and not necessary. 2.  The offset is creating an array of arrays the correct size to do the sumifs. 3. It will be fairly quick, but understand that Offset is volatile and as such any change in any open workbook will cause this to recalc.  You will need to test it yourself.  Maybe Hrun24hr will be able to come up with a different formula that does not use a volatile funtion.

Comment: Can we avoid this recalc because I have lot of sheets in the workbook and lot of data. Creating a financial model in excel so that we can implement the model in SQL

Comment: Can you please guide me which function (s) I need to look at. Because if i loose anything in the database I have to create again

Comment: As stated, I was only able to do what you requested with Offset.  Maybe someone else may be able to come up with a non volatile way.  I am unable to find one.

Comment: Nevermind can I repost this again that how to avoid a offset function

Comment: Also I would suggest making a copy of the workbook to "practice" on.

Comment: Yeah I did it's working but since you mentioned about recacl am not very aware how is it going to affect the data.

Comment: @Rakshitha it will not affect the referenced data at all.  When I say "recalc", this ONE formula will recalc every time there is a change on any open workbook.

Comment: Oh great thank you so much. Be blessed brother you give me relief now

Comment: @ScottCraner Re "*this ONE formula will recalc every time there is a change on any open workbook*", not necessarily: direct dependents of that formula will also be recalculated.

Comment: True, true, but it will not effect the base data that this points at. @JosWoolley

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a running total, SUM/INDEX can handle that:

```
=SUM($B3:INDEX(3:3,,COLUMNS($B3:B3)+1))
```

Copy over and down

Comment: Sorry this is not what I was trying, i wanted the one Scott has shown but without a volatile recalc. Also the one Scott has shown has worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

@Jos Woolley posted a nice formula using new dynamic formulas. Here another tricky formula if your columns number are not big.

```
 =CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(B3:D8)),B3:B8,B3:B8+C3:C8,B3:B8+C3:C8+D3:D8)
```

[image]

Comment: I will let you know once I have tried

Comment: Harun it worked but there are 14 columns so I'm opting for the one Jos has shared thanks to you as well

Comment: Yes, I also suggest to use that as I early stated to use scan function.